# boost::asio UDP server, how to send without having to do a receive_from first?

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio

In all the examples of the udp server, there is the code below. But in my case, I just want server to send, whether or not there is a client ready to receive. So would like to not have to use the receive_from call to get the endpoint. Can I do this in boost?

```
size_t length = sock.receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(data, max_length), sender_endpoint);
sock.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data, length), sender_endpoint);
```

Comment: You cannot send data without specified endpoint. It doesn't matter if there is or isn't a receiver on UDP but you must pick an endpoint. This is just general socket rules. Well, there is broadcast... but I don't think that this is what you want. No you don't have to use recieve from - but you need to figure out what is the endpoint you send data to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation of send_to](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/send_to/overload1.html) actually contains an example on how to construct the endpoint address and send to it, without receiving from the endpoint first. To cite:

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint destination(
    boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("1.2.3.4"), 12345);
socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data, size), destination);
```